# Rails Union Table and sort by common key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models in rails application Match and Round as follow

```
Match(id, team1, team2, series_id, event_time, event_lock_time, match_type, created_at, updated_at, match_no, match_stage)

Round(id, series_id, name, description, event_time, event_lock_time, team_ids, matches_count, created_at, updated_at)
```

I would like to add two table and sort records based on created_at something like

```
events = (Match + Round).order('created_at desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page])
```

and also apply pagination. I am using will paginations gem.

Can anyone help me how to do this in active record.

Comment: Can you share your models? If there's any association between them?

Comment: NO I dont have any association between Match and Round model

Answer (score -1):

As long as I know, models doesn't have `+` operator. So you can't do that:

`(Match + Round)`

But you can add Active Record Relations:

```
matches = Match.all
rounds = Round.all
(matches + rounds).sort_by(&:created_at)
```

You have to use sort_by or a similar way because `(matches + rounds)`  is Array and not an Active Record Relation (so `order` is not defined).

**UPDATE:**
I guess you are using will_paginate to paginate the results. It still works with array but you have to tell that and you can tell it in two ways:

1. Add this to the top of the controller: `require 'will_paginate/array'`
2. Create an initializer **config/initializers/will_paginate_with_array.rb** and require it inside this file.

Then, you can do:

```rb
(matches + rounds).sort_by(&:created_at).paginate(:page => params[:page], , :per_page => params[:per_page])
```

Comment: hey Thanks for your reply, but I would like to paginate the result as I have to serve data over api request.